# Generic type is collapsed to union when passed to another function

Tags: typescript, generics

Hello fellow StackOverflowers!

I have been trying for quite some time (with more complicated code) to achieve a generic type safe callback system that where one can register a callback to some event and this callback is added to an array of listeners for the specific event type.

It works fine when I don't use an array, but just one callback per event. But typescript gets lost when I try to use an array instead to push the callback into.

```js
enum MyEvent {
    One,
    Two
}

type Callback<T> = (arg: T) => void;

type CallbackTypes = {
    [MyEvent.One]: number
    [MyEvent.Two]: string
}

class CallbackContainer {
    callbacksA: { [E in MyEvent]: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]> } = {
        [MyEvent.One]: () => {},
        [MyEvent.Two]: () => {}
    };

    callbacksB: { [E in MyEvent]: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[] } = {
        [MyEvent.One]: [],
        [MyEvent.Two]: []
    };

    constructor() {}
    
    setListenerA<E extends MyEvent, C extends typeof this.callbacksA[E]>(this: CallbackContainer, event: E, callback: C) {
        this.callbacksA[event] = callback; // =)
    }

    getListenerA<E extends MyEvent>(event: E) {
        return this.callbacksA[event];
    }

    setListenerB<E extends MyEvent, C extends typeof this.callbacksB[E][number]>(this: CallbackContainer, event: E, callback: C) {
        const callbacks = this.callbacksB[event]; // type of callbacks is still intact
        callbacks.push(callback); // callbacks collapsed
    }

    getListenersB<E extends MyEvent>(event: E) {
        return this.callbacksB[event];
    }
}

const c = new CallbackContainer();

c.setListenerA(MyEvent.One, (a) => a + 1); // Types resolve fine
c.getListenerA(MyEvent.One); // Types resolve fine

c.setListenerB(MyEvent.One, (a) => a + 1); // Types resolve fine
c.getListenersB(MyEvent.One); // Types resolve fine
```

[Link to Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ir3InPmZLoHcNS6QyReEHqyhdHRbGPgKOPWRWKJdK5Q7848ge4QmElNMNVqdfn9ahKuHjaaoOa6vnrTUobiQKlF3dRM45Dm81umg9C0cAp6feKHFAu+6ml1nKkDHxXlOiam8DfcywwI5ZfIb1oz19D86moPguBYakjADSJg0rMNwkeOthRjd4jgTOcEBTKEoHTVBM2zLV92VPsi1PAMGCwNcNyEFwiEoKwD0nadwg2a4hB8CtQ2rCN5D5FZ-AFRQzigLgoAAaigABGADvV9AFnHTRxQJQKApSqSifFgrimR4vj4n8GTz3knCnGU9g1KIHIOJDKsdIeXi430ohBK4YTRIk6TAM0BwFNMngVIs4ANK02zw0eByPjhQy5J8kylP88yqiAA)

When pushing the callback into the array I get:

```
Argument of type 'Callback<number> | Callback<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<number> & Callback<string>'.
  Type 'Callback<number>' is not assignable to type 'Callback<number> & Callback<string>'.
    Type 'Callback<number>' is not assignable to type 'Callback<string>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

While before pushing, the compiler knows perfectly well that the type of C (the callback is):

```
C extends {
    0: Callback<number>[];
    1: Callback<string>[];
}[E][number]>
```

and the type of the callbacks array is:

```
const callbacks = {
    0: Callback<number>[];
    1: Callback<string>[];
}[E]
```

But when `push`ing they collapse to `Callback<number> | Callback<string>` and  `Callback<number>[] | Callback<string>[]` respectively. Have I run into a limitation of the typescript compiler or am I missing something obvious? If it's a limitation, are there any workarounds? Thanks!

Comment: The call signature `setListener<E extends MyEvent, C extends typeof this.callbacksB[E][number]>(this: CallbackContainer, event: E, callback: C)` is significantly more complicated than seems necessary here; does `setListener<E extends MyEvent>(event: E, callback: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>)` work for you instead?   I'm going to assume so in the answer I'm writing up.

Comment: `setListener<E extends MyEvent>(event: E, callback: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>)` will work too. I was just trying to get the compiler to work, so the `typeof this` part was a trial and error kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ease of discussion I'm going to look at the following version of your code:

```
type Callbacks = { [E in MyEvent]: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[] };

class CallbackContainer {

    callbacks: Callbacks = {
        [MyEvent.One]: [],
        [MyEvent.Two]: []
    };

    constructor() { }

    setListener<E extends MyEvent>(event: E, callback: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>) { 
      /* how to implement? */ 
    }

}
```

which is pretty much the same, except that `callback` is of a properly generic type (in your version it gets widened to a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)). And it still has the same problem in TypeScript 4.5 and below:

```
// TS 4.5-
const callbacks = this.callbacks[event]
// const callbacks: Callbacks[E]
callbacks.push(callback); // error!
// const callbacks: Callback<number>[] | Callback<string>[]
```

When you call `callbacks.push()`, the type of `callbacks` loses its genericness (genericity? genericality? whatever) and is seen only as a union.  And since both `callbacks` and `callback` are either of a union type or [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union type, the compiler forgets that they are *correlated* to each other. It worries about impossible situations, such as where `callbacks` is a `Callback<number>[]` while `callback` is a `Callback<string>`.

This is, at least up until TypeScript 4.5, a design limitation (or missing feature) in TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for a detailed discussion.

---

Luckily enough, a fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) should be released with TypeScript 4.6.  Among other things, it maintains the genericosity (‍♂️) of `callbacks.push()`, and your problem goes away:

```
// TS4.6+
callbacks.push(callback); // okay
// const callbacks: Callbacks[E]
// (method) Array<Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>>.push(
//   ...items: Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[]): number
```

So if you can upgrade to `typescript@next` or wait until TS4.6 is released, then this problem will more or less resolve itself (as long as you redefine the `callback` parameter the way I do here).

---

Until then, all you can do is use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler what it can't figure out on its own.  For example:

```
// TS4.5-
const callbacks = this.callbacks[event] as Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[];
callbacks.push(callback); // okay
```

Now there's no error, because you've taken the job of maintaining type safety away from the compiler.  You're giving your word that `callbacks` is a `Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[]`, and the compiler believes you. As long as that turns out to be true, you won't have a problem. But if you lie to the compiler, accidentally or otherwise:

```
// TS4.5-
const callbacks = this.callbacks[MyEvent.One] 
  as Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[]; // no compiler error
```

you still won't have a compiler error but you can expect problems at runtime.

---

That means: if you use type assertions, take extra care to ensure that you're doing so responsibly.  But hopefully you can make use of the fix at ms/TS#47109, which supports correlated unions without type assertions, and would catch errors like the one above:

```
// TS4.6+
const callbacks = this.callbacks[MyEvent.One];
callbacks.push(callback); // error!
```

[TS4.5 Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUQG6gC5QN4Cgq6geRGABoc8AVAdwHssBfLLVOAB2CgGEBDAGx4CMuAYwDWAHnIA+KAF4oACi4AnAOYAuKOQCUs6UmoBLACYBuRgZCpgSgGbD23PoNHlWwAM6YyuANrxkaAB0hMAAuhrgEPzW3lB+iCiWgVTU4VDuqEoWKvSMzGycvALCIp5yGHEIUBawCWhpjsWiYo3OIq5s7j4IoZI+oVB0ZlhCPFzunq0lHNSWXBbWXrFCRW3uGlOiZV54u3H+iajBRGn9pHt48QFJKaehsUOMu0KzGUpgQqjUSvI6FQyxdzAVAAGQMGVA1jEVWAAA8rCAjJ4DmhJPJgIcNAhiFAVk4ShtViUWkSXG4uj1JH9Ys9Xug8U1SrIoKgABbgwIMtY+DH1KDjQr45qbdrk7q9fpmC64LkldyBFhgdys+Sy0RaExQAD0Wqg1BEXDg0qgDyeeBUwLBEKISnc0KgcIRSNq11QaN5lix1ONSmBYCUIBZ7PlatKPMOoSleAYAJeIAyuOZREogsZMzmCx+GsYQkCQNB4IR1nkKKSIRxih0MmkXCgAGooABGbO5i0F63WdwluplogaqBAA)

[TS4.6 Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20211229#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-YyOh4ZZJJMrVerAtGDFYIOtbYzA21g-a+qEtBFINElE88ADdipgWCIUQlO5oVA4QikbVrqg0bzLFjqXKoEpgWAlCAWeylZrSjzDqEzLsGADzZahMyiJRE20ZnMFj9tYwhIEgaDwQjrPIUUkQjjFDoZNIuFAANRQACMq-XRa3pes7j3dQPRG1UCAA)

Comment: You said "... except that callback is of a properly generic type (in your version it gets widened to a union type)". Does using `typeof this.` cause the conversion to a Union there?

Comment: Sort of; the compiler doesn't see that `Callbacks[E][number]` is the same as `Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>`, even though this must be true whenever `E` is not the full `MyEvent` union.  To make it easier on the compiler, we want `Parameters<typeof callbacks.push>[0]` to be the same exact thing as `typeof callback`.

Comment: In your 4.6 playground, when I change `const callbacks =` to `const callbacks: Array<Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>> =` the compiler says `'Callbacks[E]' is not assignable to type 'Callback<CallbackTypes[E]>[]'`, while this is the exact type that callbacks seems to have when examining `.push`. Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't really know the details of how quickinfo works with these distributed object types in TS4.6; it's a good question and maybe should be asked separately, or commented in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) or something.